# How to extract full prices with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

Hi i am trying to scrap e-commerce page, but cant get prices.

I have page with this lines:

```
<span class="price">255,<sup>99</sup>€</span>
<span class="price">255 €</span>
```

But i can't extracts all price to one line.

I tried:

> response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()

But it ignores text in `<sup>` tag...
What i am doing wrong? please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another slash before text. So it addresses ALL nodes.

```
    response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]//text()').extract()

Text='255,'
Text='99'
Text='€'
```

Comment: but how to join them to one field?

Answer (score 1):

You should put double splash instead of single one.

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]//text()').extract()
```

This statement returns all text under the specified tag as list object.
Note that the returned list may have some useless elements just like empty or return carriage character.
So you can use regex if you want extract only price information.

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]//text()').re(r'[\d.,]+')
```

The currency symbol was ignored.

```
['255,','99','255']
```

Finally if you want get 255.99 from the page

```
''.join(response.xpath('//span[@class="price"][1]//text()').re(r'[\d.,]+')).replace(",",".")
```

You get all products first.

Final code:

```js
products = response.xpath('//*[@class="catalog-table"]//td')
for prod in products:
    price = ''.join(prod.xpath('//span[@class="price"][1]//text()').re(r'[\d.,]+')).replace(",",".")
    print price
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this on page https://www.varle.lt/m/mobilieji-telefonai?p=4 in shell, but it gives me now everything in one field.

Comment: Do you use scrapy? If then do this. First you should iterate all products one by one. you can get a list of products with this ('//*[@class="catalog-table"]//td')   and then iterate all products and get the price from each product. I will edit my Answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Check source HTML. There is  in the source:

I was searching for the same question for the whole day and find this answer perfect for this

```
response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').get()
```